# How do you control the number of loops on a bevel of a path?

Tags: edit-mode, path

Changing the resolution just doesn't do the trick. How can I control the bevel on a path to change the number of loops it uses to comprise the bevel?

Answer (score 0):

It is in the resolution of the host path, not of the target bevel path.